# Remove an url scheme from an App in developers.facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, url-scheme

I have an app which is already in the app store. I'm working on adding Facebook ads and I found a really strange thing. In developer.facebook > Tools&Support > app-ads-helper, the link : **https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper/?id=my_app_id**

Under **iOS Setup** there is a row named **Install Invalidation** and it is mentioned : The following schemes will be used for install invalidation: [fbMY_APP_ID://, MY_APP_BUNDEL://, MY_APP_NAME://, **ANOTHER_APP_NAME**://]

This strange url scheme can cause a problem.
When I select the redirection link to MY APP on iTunes, the description of the other app appears. 
I don't understand how this list gets filled and how can I remove the strange url scheme ?

Comment: this section is not filled automatically, it is entered by a developer. Can you not just delete the ones that aren't relevant?

Comment: I think that every time I change my url scheme and connect to Facebook, this url scheme will be added automatically to that list in developers.facebook. The problem is that I don't find how to edit the list so I can remove the ones I don't need anymore. could it be available only for admins ? I'm a dev for the app.